# Is there a way I could href to a local const file in a link tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I have an SVG icon that I would like to link it as an icon for the browser title bar.

```js
const svgIcon = <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                    <path "something"></path>
                </svg>
```

and then a link tag that would add to the head of HTML (jsx) as

```html
<link rel="icon" href={svgIcon} type="image/svg+xml">
```

Is there a way I would be able to link the image that I have as a variable to show as a browser title bar icon?

The image is an import and I cant save it as a file to link it.

Comment: I'm working with `react` to do this. I just tried to simplify the question. Let me know if anyone wants the react part and I would be happy to share.

Comment: It may not be an answer for your question, but you should remember that not all the browsers supports SVGs in favicons https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg

Comment: convert it to a data URL and use that.

Comment: and even favicon should not be generated through js

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson

Answer (score 0):

Don't populate favicon through JS. Use it directly in html by saving your file to svg:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.svg" type='image/svg+xml'>
```

But it's strongly recommended that you use ico or png format. Just google for "svg to ico" or "svg to png" and you can use online converter to get it for use in your website.

Comment: Any updates to this import has to be maintained manually if I do so. I'm trying to see if there is a better way to do this without having to save it as an `.png` file

Comment: You don't have to import anything. You can use it in public/index.html

Comment: I'm using `react` and this SVG image is a component and is imported like `const svgIcon = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<IconSomething />);` This component `<IconSomething />` is maintained by someone else.